# Accessing SvelteKit stores in PageLoad

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

So - if I try to access a writeable within a +page.js then it just returns empty.

```js
import { isAuthenticated, user } from '../../authstore';

export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {

    console.log ('doing load')
    console.log('is auth = ', isAuthenticated)

    if (! isAuthenticated) {
        throw redirect(302, '/');
    }

    return {test:''};
}
```

As you can see, I'm adding this to a +page.js to check logged in status and if not, redirecting them to the root.

However - isAuthenticated isn't accessible. Is this because it's running on the server rather than the client?

Answer (score 2):

Usually login information is stored in cookies; the UI cannot be a reliable authority on this. The page load functions run on the client and the server (server-side rendering happens on initial navigation), so it is not really a suitable place to deal with this.

In general you would use the `+page.server.js` or `+layout.server.js` files, as they always run on the server. The load functions in the server files have access to [`cookies`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#cookies-and-headers). If you check the login status via cookies in a layout file, you can have a single check location for an entire sub-tree of the application.

The login status could then be handed off to a page or layout file as the initial value of an authentication store, which then can be updated dynamically on the page if necessary. If the authentication currently happens without involving the server at all (e.g. via some third-party provider), I would recommend checking documentation on how to transfer authentication information securely to the server.

Comment: Good advice. Im wiring in auth0. However the issue I’m having is I can access stores in page.svelte but accessing the same store in page.js isn’t working. I’m assuming this should be possible?

Comment: No, it should not. As noted, the code may run on the server and there is no way to pass stores between client and server. Also, it would not be possible for the server to differentiate between users when accessing a single object instance.

Answer (score 2):

+page.js can't use the $ shortcut to access the value from a writable store. I believe the dollar sign is called autosubscription and it doesn't work on Page.js

My solution is to use subscribe on the writable:

```
let authed = false;
isAuthenticated.subscribe(v => {
    authed = v
})
console.log('authuser', authuser)
```

This works.

As H.B. notes however, for authentication there may be other considerations you want to make such as using session data.

Comment: Also, when you subscribe to store, you generally also want to make sure to unsubscribe (call function returned from `subscribe`). For auto-subscriptions Svelte does that automatically when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Ah right, yes. I'm assuming I'd do that immediately after the variable is assigned.

Comment: If you just need the value once, you can use the `get` function from `svelte/store`.